# Magento reload page with one of 2 payment methods

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules, payment-methods

I have a question and I want to know how to implement this.

My customer has 2 different payment methods. 
 - iDeal 
 - Cash on Delivery

I have setup the price cart rules and the first choice the customer can pick is iDeal.
This gives them a 2% discount. However, If they choose the pay with cash on delivery the amount is changed but the discount amount is still showing, so this is confusing the customers.

I have found this file in Magento where I want to make the change:

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml

```
<dl class="sp-methods" id="checkout-payment-method-load">
<?php
$methods = $this->getMethods();
$oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
?>
<?php
foreach ($methods as $_method):
$_code = $_method->getCode();
?>
<dt>
?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
<input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
<input id="p_method_cashondelivery" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>'); window.location.reload();"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
<?php else: ?>
<span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
<?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
</dt>
<?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
<dd>
<?php echo $html; ?>
</dd>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

Somewhere around line 45 I have this code:

```
<input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
```

What I want to do is have this rule stay and add another line of code to change the Payment method like this:

```
<input id="p_method_cashondelivery" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>'); window.location.reload();"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
```

But this result in the page have 2 radio buttons for each payment method, not so great idea.

Which code do I need to add to change the p_method_cashondelivery?

Br,

Steve

Answer (score 2):

This is not an ideal solution, you're patching a problem at its endpoint rather than fixing the real problem. I'm a bit preoccupied today so I can't delve into the proper solution. For now, the answer to your question is:

Change:

```
<?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
<input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
<input id="p_method_cashondelivery" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>'); window.location.reload();"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
<?php else: ?>
```

Into:

```
<?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
<input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" 
       type="radio" name="payment[method]" 
       title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" 
       onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')<?=($_code == 'cashondelivery' ? 'window.location.reload();' : '');?>"
       <?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
<?php else: ?>
```

I added `<?=($_code == 'cashondelivery' ? 'window.location.reload();' : '');?>` to the onclick parameter, this only outputs the reload code when that method is clicked.

A couple of small things:

1) You don't want to edit this file in the base/default. Copy it with it's exact path into whatever your active theme is. Making it `/app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml`

2) I'm not sure reloading so soon after clicking will have the proper effect, be careful that you're not reloading uselessly.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Rian,

Thanks for the reply. Regarding the small things, I was planning on doing that after the code works.

I applied the changes but nothing is happening.
What I also tried was adding a cart rule with no discount to the checkout when you select cash on delivery.

The problem could be in this part:

`<?=($_code == 'p_method_cashondelivery' ? 'window.location.reload();' : '');?>`

I'll try some other stuff and wait for your reply.
Many thanks again.

Br,

Steve

Comment: Whoops >_<   it should be `<?=($_code == 'cashondelivery' ? 'window.location.reload();' : '');?>`. Adjusted the answer as well